# Can't see polygons of a shapefile but attribute table is fine

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, extensions

for some reason I can't visualize the shapefile I create even when trying by Zoom to layer. When checking the attribute table is fine. I attach here and image of the shapefile information just in case can help.

[image]

Comment: Did you change the CRS of the layer after you loaded it?

Comment: The extent of the layer is about 460x490 kilometers and there are some features at coordinates (0 0). Perhaps you just do not see any of the 23 features on the map when it is zoomed to that rather large BBOX. Perhaps it helps to go to attribute table, select one feature at a time, and zoom to selected.

Comment: Perhaps you can share the shapefile so others can check it